# Huxtable package for R: Align Columns Not Working As Expected in Knitted Doc

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using RStudio version 1.1.456, which is running R version 3.5.1. I am running on Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit. I am using huxtable package version 4.3.0.

I'm trying to change various aspects of the huxtable when it is knitted to a word document. I'm finding that a lot of the options (such as right_padding, left_padding, width, or col_width) don't seem to be having any effect on the table formatting in either the word document, or when I test the formatting directly in the RStudio console.

In addition, the align function does not seem to be "listening". I am trying to left-align my first column:

```
ht1 <- as_hux(table(other_cei_data$location)) 
caption(ht1) <- "Where is your institution located?"
ht1[1,1] <- "Location" ## add proper col names
ht1[1,2] <- "Frequency"
align(ht1)[,1] <- 'left'
ht1
```

When I use this code in the RStudio console, this works just fine.

[console table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TslGh.png)

But when I knit to a word document, the first column is center aligned.

[word document table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trw7f.png)

When I put in arguments 'center' and 'right', the column is aligned as expected. I've also noticed that the default for the table in Word is for the first column to be left aligned until I add my column name. If I don't add any column names, the default is left-aligned, but regardless of what I specify, the column is always left-aligned.

I've also tried building a hux table manually with the same result (code below); 'right' and 'center' work fine, but 'left' is center-aligned:

```
ht1b <-hux(Location = c("Elsewhere in Canada","Ontario","USA or International"), 
           Frequency = c(10,13,4), 
           add_colnames = TRUE)
align(ht1b)[,1] <- 'left'
ht1b
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm hoping someone can help. I'd really like to be able to use huxtable, as it seems like the best option for tables in RMarkdown reports, but I'm finding that the customization is not behaving as expected.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Could you report it at the github site? Ta - huxtable author.

Answer (score 0):

To print directly to Word with huxtable, you need the latest github version (will be  4.4.0):

`devtools::install_github("hughjonesd/huxtable")`

Then your plan should work. At the moment, huxtable prints out a markdown table if it detects it is in a word document.

An alternative is to convert manually to flextable:

`as_flextable(ht1)`

which, with recent versions of the flextable/officer packages, knows how to autoprint itself in Word.